# Why aren't Wii games readable, even with a different disk?

Tags: technical-issues, nintendo-wii

I have a Wii mini console that no longer will play our most-played games, like Mario Galaxy 1, 2, and Mario Kart. It will however still play games I never played, like Paintball.

I purchased a new copy of Mario Kart, thinking the issue was the older disk being scratched, but even the newer disk without scratches returns errors.

Is there possibly some other reason and a fix for why these disks can't be read?

Comment: Have you tried resetting/formatting its memory? It's common that a game copies some files on the console itself to improve the performance and reduce loading time, you need the disc just to run it. Probably those files got corrupted somehow and you get an error when your Wii tries to execute them.